# Getting response from async 1st api call(takes time to get the response) and passing it on to the 2nd async api in order to get the final response

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Both 1st and 2nd api calls are post calls

```
someFunction(floor){
floor.entities.forEach(elementId => {
                        let desiredTempForZone;
                        this.getDesiredHeatingTemp(elementId._id).subscribe((des) => 
                                {
                                    desiredTempForZone = des
                                });
                        console.log(desiredTempForZone);
})
}

getDesiredHeatingTemp(eleId){
    //1st api call
    return this.siteService.getScheduleParamsByRoomRef('temp and air and desired and heating', eleId)
    .pipe(
    switchMap(a => {
        console.log(a)
        const obs = a.forEach((m)=>{
          //console.log(m)

        //this is custom function
        let pointId = this.helperService.stripHaystackTypeMapping(m.rows[0]['id']).split(' ')[0];

        //2nd api call
        return this.siteService.getHisPointData(pointId, 'current')
      })
      return forkJoin(obs)
  }))
}
```

The response which I get from 1st api call looks like

```
a=
cols: (23) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
meta: {ver: "2.0"}
rows: [{…}]

a=
 cols: (23) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
 meta: {ver: "2.0"}
 rows: Array(1)
      0:
       air: "m:"
       desired: "m:"
       id: "r:5d906-9600-desire"
       kind: "Number"
       __proto__: Object
       length: 1
       __proto__: Array(0)
```

//2nd api call

```
  return this.siteService.getHisPointData(pointId, 'current').subscribe(e => console.log(e))
```

**ISSUE**
I am also able to get response from 2nd api call but only when I subscribe(as above) to *(getHisPointData) api*  whereas I wanted to pass this response to **obs** which would inturn be passed to the below calling function

```
this.getDesiredHeatingTemp(elementId._id).subscribe((des) => 
                                {
                                    desiredTempForZone = des
                                });
```

But **obs** is undefined

The 2nd api call response

```
       {meta: {…}, cols: Array(2), rows: Array(1)}
     cols: (2) [{…}, {…}]
     meta: {ver: "2.0", id: "r:5d8df1fc3942df083a4539d5", hisStart: "n:0.0", hisEnd: "n:0.0"}
     rows: Array(1)
        0:
          ts: "t:2019-09-30T13:40:58.761Z UTC"
          val: "n:65"
          __proto__: Object
          length: 1
        __proto__: Array(0)
    __proto__: Object
   {meta: {…}, cols: Array(2), rows: Array(1)}
     cols: (2) [{…}, {…}]
     meta: {ver: "2.0", id: "r:5d8df1fc3942df083a4539d5", hisStart: "n:0.0", hisEnd: "n:0.0"}
     rows: Array(1)
        0:
          ts: "t:2019-09-30T13:40:58.761Z UTC"
          val: "n:70"
          __proto__: Object
          length: 1
        __proto__: Array(0)
    __proto__: Object
           {meta: {…}, cols: Array(2), rows: Array(1)}
     cols: (2) [{…}, {…}]
     meta: {ver: "2.0", id: "r:5d8df1fc3942df083a4539d5", hisStart: "n:0.0", hisEnd: "n:0.0"}
     rows: Array(1)
        0:
          ts: "t:2019-09-30T13:40:58.761Z UTC"
          val: "n:90"
          __proto__: Object
          length: 1
        __proto__: Array(0)
    __proto__: Object
```

**Older implementation where I was getting final value**

```
 this.siteService.getScheduleParamsByRoomRef('temp and air and desired and heating', eleId).subscribe(({ rows }) => {
       if (rows.length > 0) {
           rows.forEach((row) => {
               let pointId = this.helperService.stripHaystackTypeMapping(row['id']).split(' ')[0];

               this.siteService.getHisPointData(pointId, 'current').subscribe(({ rows }) => {
                   if (rows.length > 0) {
                       let HeatingDesired = this.helperService.stripHaystackTypeMapping(rows[0].val);

                   }
               });
           });

       }

   });
```

Comment: I think it should be `a.rows.forEach` instead of `a.forEach`

Comment: @YashRami, oh yes , now the execution goes inside , my bad I missed that , but one more thing can you suggest please , once the execution gets inside I am able to get pointId but the 2nd api call doesn't happen

Comment: are you sure ? Did you check your network tab in chrome inspect is there any api call there?

Comment: @YashRami , I am getting obs as undefined will check the 2nd api call response , will update

Comment: @YashRami , I checked , 2nd api call happens but obs is undefined so return forkJoin(obs) , has undefined , could you please suggest , what might be the issue

Comment: @YashRami , I have posted the older implementation where I was getting the final value for reference , please suggest

Comment: I think this happens bcs there is a function call after the first api call so what I suggest is that try to use async await approch for calling that function and after that on “then” section of that function call you will get the value of the “pointId” so you can use that “pointId” to call your second api i hope it helps you out 

Comment: @YashRami , I was also thinking of async await , I have updated the post , so I am getting the response for 2nd api as well :) , but only the issue is , I am not passing it(obs) correctly in the parent calling function , can you provide a fix for this issue , thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200177/discussion-between-enthu-and-yash-rami).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

```js
someFunction(floor){
floor.entities.forEach(elementId => {
  let desiredTempForZone;
   this.getDesiredHeatingTemp(elementId._id).subscribe((des) => 
   {
     desiredTempForZone = des
   });
 })
}

getDesiredHeatingTemp(eleId){
    //1st api call
    return this.siteService.getScheduleParamsByRoomRef('temp and air and desired and 
      heating', eleId)
    .pipe(
    switchMap(a => {
        let secondApiCallUrlList = [];
        const obs = a.rows.forEach((m)=>{
          //this is custom function
          let pointId = this.helperService.stripHaystackTypeMapping(m.rows[0] 
            ['id']).split(' ')[0]; // here we dont need to create the asynchronisation block because as you said before older implemention is working as expected 

        //2nd api call
       secondApiCallUrlList.push(this.siteService.getHisPointData(pointId, 'current'));
      })
      return forkJoin(secondApiCallUrlList); // so here we are passing the whole array so while you subscribe you will get all response once all api call finished 
  }))
}
```

let me know if it is not woking :)

Comment: sry did't got you here we are creating a url list for second api call how would we get the 1st api response on that

Comment: you are getting this undefined inside this subscription `this.getDesiredHeatingTemp(elementId._id).subscribe((des) => 
   { ... }
 `
?

Comment: can you try to subscribe the `des` like this `des.subscribe(response => {
   console.log(response);
})` let me know the result

Comment: Forkjoin is return the observer which contain the response of all the api calls thats why

Comment: @Enthu sure mate

Answer (score 1):

First problem, here:

```
const obs = a.forEach((m)=> {
```

that'll be *undefined*, because *undefined* is the only thing a `forEach` returns. You need to use a `map` instead

```
const obs = a.map((m) => {
```

and `forkJoin` the returned observables:

```
return forkJoin(...obs)
```

And the same pattern for `someFunction`: `map` an array into an array of observables (*don't* subscribe inside the mapping functions, return observables, not subscriptions), `forkJoin` the created array of observables, finally subscribe and consume the results.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the basic thing forEach doesnt return anything

Comment: This part I believe I need to take care of , "And the same pattern for someFunction: map an array into an array of observables"